# Overheating as a result of water not returning from reservoir to radiator

Tags: radiator

Please can someone help me out with this problem of overheating. I had one honda civic 2004 SE that is recently giving me headache in fact I thought of selling the car but I wouldn't like to do that to innocent buyer so I choose to repair. The major problem is that whenever the water in the radiator transfer to the reservoir it won't return to the radiator and the car will begin to overheat. I have tried many mechanic to fix the problem but situation remain the same. Repairing cost is not the problem but need a specific solution to the problem. I wouldn't want to loose that car because of this please can someone help me out.
Thanks.
Julius

Comment: If the coolant is not flowing, then either you have a blockage, or the pump has problems. Worth looking at them first.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this caused by a leaking radiator cap ( not the cap on the reservoir tank ). The engine heats fairly quickly, pressurizes and pushes fluid into the overflow tank. Then it may let pressure ( air ) out while running, or when off, the engine cools slowly and sucks in air instead of fluid from the reservoir. A new radiator cap is cheap and easy to install so worth a try. Do it when the engine is cold and clean the seat area of the cap.